# GUID comparison weirdness

Tags: c#, .net, guid

.NET has two GUID data types: [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which orders GUIDs in the "natural" way, and [SqlGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid(v=vs.110).aspx), which considers the six bytes after the final dash to be most significant. This difference is explained in detail here: [MSDN: Comparing GUID and uniqueidentifier Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254976(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, in both cases, the following should hold (assuming that all `...`s are equal):

```
57d0affe-... < 57d0afff-... < 57d0b000-...
```

If that is the case, why do I get the following output (see comments)?

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var g1 = new SqlGuid("57d0affe-9d9d-11e4-bec2-e840f2ad1632");
        var g2 = new SqlGuid("57d0afff-9d9d-11e4-bec2-e840f2ad1632");
        var g3 = new SqlGuid("57d0b000-9d9d-11e4-bec2-e840f2ad1632");

        Console.WriteLine(g1 < g2); // prints True
        Console.WriteLine(g2 < g3); // prints False <- ?
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that `g2 < g3` should yield True as well. Did I misunderstand something or is this some bug in the framework? When using plain `Guid` instead of `SqlGuid`, the output is twice `True`, as expected.

Comment: Why are you comparing GUID values in the first place? I'm not sure there's a standard for ordering GUIDs.  If you want an orderable column use an integer or something other than a GUID.

Comment: @DStanley: When using GUIDs as primary keys (or clustered indexes) in SQL Server, ordering *is* important (performance-wise). That's why things like `newsequentialid()` exist.

Comment: If you need more context: We use the Win32 API function UuidCreateSequential to create IDs for records that will be inserted into the database in the future. A unit test for our .NET wrapper to UuidCreateSequential started failing every now and then, which alerted me to this issue.

Comment: You might check out [this column](http://www.shirmanov.com/2010/05/generating-newsequentialid-compatible.html) if you want to try and replicate SQL Server's behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the comparison goes byte by byte. So the first thing you're asking is "is 0xff smaller than 0x00?" Obviously, it's not :)

That's of course why the SQL guid notation is "weird" - it's "twice inverted". I don't know why this was decided to be so for `uniqueidentifier` in MS SQL (I assume it allowed for better hashing or something), but `SqlGuid` has to have the same behaviour, so it just gets the whole `byte[]` and goes one byte after another. The first byte is the last byte of the first group, the second byte is the next-to-last of the first group etc.

**EDIT**:

To add more information, the Microsoft standard GUID structure is defined as this:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

When using byte-by-byte comparison, the first three groups get native-endianness, while the last one is always big-endian.

This is the GUID used in SQL server, and also the one that `SqlGuid` emulates. The native .NET `System.Guid` does the same thing in it's `CompareTo` method.

The RFCC 4122 GUID actually displays the same behaviour on big-endian machines, the only difference is that it's always big-endian for all the groups. As far as I'm aware, it's not described to have any designed ordering at all.

Comparing GUIDs for anything but equality doesn't really make much sense. If you need to do that, there's special GUIDs (like sequential or time-based GUIDs) that give you a more reasonable distribution of values while still being reasonably unique.

Since it's not defined and it doesn't really make too much sense, comparison byte-by-byte or char-by-char are the two most obvious to have - human would expect char-by-char, because that's how we see the value, but for the computer, byte-by-byte is more reasonable. But what's even more reasonable is field-by-field - and that's what's happening there.

Comment: So you are claiming that the byte order of the *first* component is reversed in SqlGuid/uniqueidentifier as opposed to Guid/WinApi?

Comment: @Heinzi Not just the first one, actually. The Microsoft standard GUID has the first three groups in native endianness (i.e. little-endian on x86), and only the last one is big-endian. The RFC standard GUID has all of the groups as big-endian. The reason is basically that the Microsoft GUID structure is actually defined as `DWORD, WORD, WORD, BYTE[8]`, so it gets its endianness partially from the computer native byte order.

Comment: I see. If you use that information to improve your answer (how exactly does a SqlGuid/uniqueidentifier differ from a Microsoft GUID and what influence does that have on ordering -- I guess both do a "byte by byte comparison", so that's not really the difference), I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The Comparison is a bit more complex.

Firstofall there is some order defined:

```
  private static readonly int[] x_rgiGuidOrder = new int[16]
    {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 8, 9, 6, 7, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3};
```

then there is this method

```
private static EComparison Compare(SqlGuid x, SqlGuid y) {
        //Swap to the correct order to be compared
        for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfGuid; i++) {
            byte    b1, b2;

            b1 = x.m_value [x_rgiGuidOrder[i]];
            b2 = y.m_value [x_rgiGuidOrder[i]];
            if (b1 != b2)
                return(b1 < b2) ? EComparison.LT : EComparison.GT;
        }
        return EComparison.EQ;
    }
```

However this is not the whole story, what really is the reason is the constructor from string:

```
    public SqlGuid(String s) {
        m_value = (new Guid(s)).ToByteArray();
    }
```

It creates a new GUID and then uses its byte-representation.

and this gives us the following byte-values:

```
g2 : 255 175 208 87 157 157 228 17 190 194 232 64 242 173 22 50
g3 : 0   176 208 87 157 157 228 17 190 194 232 64 242 173 22 50
```

And there we can see that the 255 is bigger than 0 and not the other way round.

You can find the full source [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLGuid@cs/1305376/SQLGuid@cs)
Fiddle how to get the byte-representation is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dh09JW)

Comment: How does that explain the output? `af` (at order position 12 in g1) is smaller than `b0` (at order position 12 in g2).

Comment: Yeah i just saw. It doesnt. But this may add to the understanding what happens unter the hood.

Comment: @Heinzi now it does explain.